# How to write a Klass.any_instance_with_id(id).expects(:method) in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When writing tests using RSpec, I regularly have the need to express something like

```
Klass.any_instance_with_id(id).expects(:method)
```

Main reason is that in my test, I often have the object that should receive that method call available, but due to the fact that ActiveRecord, when loading the object with that id from the database, will create a different instance, I can't put the "expects" on my own instance

Sometimes I can stub the find method to force ActiveRecord to load my instance, sometimes I can stub other methods, but having that "any_instance_with_id" would make life so much easier...

Can't image I'm the first having this problem... So if any of you found a "workaround", I'd be glad to find out!

Example illustrating the need:

controller spec:

```
describe 'an authorized email' do
  let(:lead) { create(:lead, status: 'approved') }

  it "should invoice its organisation in case the organisation exceeds its credit limit" do
    lead.organisation.expects :invoice_leads
    get :email
  end
end
```

controller:

```
def email
  leads = Lead.approved

  leads.each do |lead|
    lead.organisation.invoice_leads if lead.organisation.credit_limit_exceeded?
  end

  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems weird to me you need that for specs.

You should take the problem one level higher: when your app tries to retrieve the record.

Example:

```
#code 
@user = User.find(session[:user_id])

# spec
let(:fake_user) { mock_model 'User', method: false }

it 'description' do
  User.should_receive(:find).and_return fake_user
  fake_user.expects(:method)

  #...
end
```

---

Order/invoice example:

```
let(:order)   { mock_model 'order', invoice: invoice }
let(:invoice) { mock_model 'Invoice', 'archive!' => false }
```

Comment: The records I'm talking about are typically associations that are "buried" inside a top-level record. I haven't found an equivalent for "find" to override to catch them when they're loaded from the database. Example is an order, associated with an invoice, that, when the invoice itself is marked "balanced", should get a message "archive!"

Comment: show your code and spec please :) in the meantime I edited my answer